# Django не заходит в админку

Tags: python, django

Чистый только созданный пустой проект. При попытке войти по локалхост-админ выдаёт `OperationalError at /admin/ no such table: django_session`. В `settings` все нужные аппсы есть, в `urls` тоже путь к ней на первом месте(более того - единственный).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ты не сделал первоначальные миграции, поэтому джанга не может найти нужную табличку.
Введи python manage.py migrate